# Joomla Contact Component - can I change "Miscellaneous Information" to "Bio"?

Tags: overrides, contact, component-configuration

I don't want my board members bio's to be called miscellaneous information. To avoid that I'm putting bio's in the address field! This is not a good permanent solution. I would like to know if there is a way to change the label from "Miscellaneous Information" to "Bio". The feature is good for my application. The name, miscellaneous information, not so much.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take the [tour] and have a look at other questions while you wait for support.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an language override: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla
[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Edfromzi please award the green tick to this answer so that the systems stops bumping it to the top of the questions pile.